# Ajax call returns a Class 'db' not found error even if database connection already defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to update my contents using ajax. By just choosing dropdown values, the contents then populate new values based on the dropdown value being selected. But everytime I choose a value from my dropdown, it returns a Class 'db' not found error and other functions I already put on my required_once seems not working also. I have been trying to solve this for 2 days now but it is still not working. Can somebody please help me with this? Thanks. Here are my codes:

Note that when my_file.php is loaded, the course_overview_functions.php is called and the else part is loaded and it returns the appropriate values. When the ajax call is executed, if part returns true, it then returns the class 'db' not found error.

my_file.php

```
require_once 'includes/course_overview_functions.php';  

$course_array = array();
$pid_shown = array();
$course_array = ajax_request_val();
```

my_file.php (javascript part)

```
$(':input').change(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        $('.minimal_table').html('<img src="../images/loading_trans.gif"  style="position:relative; margin:350px; margin-top:250px;" />');
        alert($(this).val());

       var val_id = $(this).val();

       var postData = {val_id:val_id, ajax:1 };

$.ajax({
  url: "../includes/course_overview_functions.php",
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.minimal_table').html(data);
    },2000);
     console.log(data);
  },
  });

 });
```

course_overview_functions.php

```
function ajax_request_val(){


$val_id = $_POST['val_id'];
$field = "course_type";

if(isset($val_id)){


  $plans = db::getTable('plan',$field,$val_id);
            foreach ($plans as $plan) {
                if (eventAccessLevel(null, $plan['plan_id']) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                    $course_array[] = getCourseDetails(null, $plan['plan_id']);
                    $pid_shown[] = $plan['plan_id'];
                }
            }
            $events = db::getTable('tbl_event',$field,$val_id);
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                if (!in_array($event['plan_id'], $pid_shown)) {
                    $event_id = $event['event_id'];
                    if (eventAccessLevel($event_id, null) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                        $course_array[] = getCourseDetails($event_id, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            return $course_array;
}

else{

            $plans = db::getTable('plan');
            foreach ($plans as $plan) {
                if (eventAccessLevel(null, $plan['plan_id']) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                    $course_array[] = getCourseDetails(null, $plan['plan_id']);
                    $pid_shown[] = $plan['plan_id'];
                }
            }
            $events = db::getTable('tbl_event');
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                if (!in_array($event['plan_id'], $pid_shown)) {
                    $event_id = $event['event_id'];
                    if (eventAccessLevel($event_id, null) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                        $course_array[] = getCourseDetails($event_id, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            return $course_array;
   }    
  }
```

databaseconnect.php

```
public static function getTable($tableName,$field='',$type_id='') {
        if (!self::$db) self::connect();

        if(!empty($type_id)){
            $tableName = self::$db->escape_string($tableName);
            return self::getObjects('SELECT * FROM `' . $tableName . '` WHERE `'. $field .'` = `'. $type_id .'`;');
        }
        else{
            $tableName = self::$db->escape_string($tableName);
            return self::getObjects('SELECT * FROM `' . $tableName . '`;');
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'db' not found in /home/cm/public_html/includes/course_overview_functions.php on line 207
```

Comment: Did you include your db in `course_overview_functions.php`?

Comment: Try to double check your spelling some sort of that. Since there is no case that it won't connect because it is included. Try to put the `course_overview_functions.php` in the url for smarter debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Your databaseconnect... you have a function there but no class defined. You need to have a `class db` defined.

Comment: Sorry I did not shoew how I connect to my databse here but this is already connected. But it is works in my inital load, the data were retrieve successfully, it is just when I call my ajax that it wont connect to my databse anymore